# Add subview launch image in app delegate

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates

What I ideally would like to do is change the launch image programmatically inside of the app delegate. However, reading online has left me to believe that there is no possible way to programmatically change the Default.png image programatically. But I had a thought. What would happen if I programmatically added a UIImageView to the app delegate window and brought the view to front? Here's the code I have so far. But it's not adding when I start up the app delegate. Inside of the log statements, I see the image, but it's not adding on the actual screen. Could someone please double check my code to see what I am doing wrong here?

AppDelegate.m

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver: self selector: @selector(reachabilityChanged:) name: kReachabilityChangedNotification object: nil];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:
                  @"some website that returns an image"];

    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData: [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url]];
    //UImage is not null, and prints to the screen
    NSLog(@"%@",image);
    //Allocates a UIIMageview to be placed on the window.
    UIImageView * splashView = [[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0, 320, 480)]autorelease];

    //Sets the imageview image.
    splashView.image = image;
    //Is this right? Adding  the UIImageView to the window?
    [self.window addSubview:splashView];
    //Am I doing this right? Setting the image view at "index 0"?

    [self.window bringSubviewToFront:splashView];
}
```

NOTE: I realize it is against apple's human interface guidelines to do this, but it's part of my requirements. Hopefully I am clear for everyone.

Comment: You are downloading the image in the main thread. Maybe you can try other approach, like caching the image and show it in the next time the user opens the app...

Comment: Really? So the only way it would work is to cache it and then load up, huh. I'll give it a try.

Comment: This will not happen as you are thinking.. Because the app delegate comes into the picture after the app will display launch image.So no way to make launch image dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. iOS display Default.png image BEFORE your application start...

For your code, don't do that... if the user are in edge mode, your application can take a while before start (time to load image) or even crash (timeout after 30 seconds)

It's better to pre-load your image and display it in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: if exists.

For your initial question (image don't display), try to put your code AFTER

`[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];`

But remember: don't do that ! ;)

Comment: Hah! Yeah, but I kinda need to. Claudio had a good idea to cache the image and then try loading it. I'll give that a go.

Comment: Yes it's what i said with "pre-load": load image in application, save it and check if image exists in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions. If yes, display it...

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible to alter the launch images in any way, you could load another image straight after the launch image goes. These are known as splash screens but are not normally welcome in the iOS world. Please read the [Apple Human Interface Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/LaunchImages.html) and [iOS App Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/App-RelatedResources/App-RelatedResources.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH6-SW12) very carefully. Everything you need to know about launch images are in here.

> It’s often said that people spend no more than a minute or two evaluating a new app. When you make the most of this brief period by presenting useful content immediately, you pique the interest of new users and give all users a superior experience.
>
> As much as possible, avoid displaying a splash screen or other startup experience. It’s best when users can begin using your app immediately.

You might as well just give up now trying to add an image to the launch image this is impossible unless you do it in something like photoshop and then add it as your new `Default.png` image.